# Change label of fields for a post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created a post type , say member.

Now while adding/editing a post from admin panel, it have pre defined fields like title, description.

But I want to change the label of `title` to read `name`.

Field I will not change... I will call it as get_the_title().

But how to change that label and that is for that particular post type ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13004/120302 - this should help you with your problem

Comment: Thanks buddy !!!